# Remove drag shadow from HTML5 draggable

Tags: html

Im working with HTML5 drag and drop. Im trying to prevent the "shadow" of the item as you see in the bottom right corner. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

[image: Text]

The `.draggable` is the selector element. I'm using the `.draggable-layer` as the clickable attribute to "protect" whats underneath.

```html
<div class="draggable" draggable="true" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <div>
    <div class="draggable-content table-element">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="black" width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
            </svg>
      <span> Item </span></div>
    <div class="draggable-layer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes there is. If you want us to help you however, we need to see the code. This can possible be done with a CSS rule.

Comment: Added @KIKOSoftware, is it enough or you also need the parent div?

Comment: what do you mean by _the "shadow" of the item as you see in the bottom right corner_?

Comment: You have multiple `class="...."` in the snippet but no CSS is provided. Please add all relevant CSS classes into the CSS part of the snippet. Also, what you see might be caused by default styling as defined by the browser, so please mention what Make and Version of browser you are using.

Comment: @DonnyvanV do you want to hide the translucent representation of the draggable elements that follows your cursor or the draggable element from its initial position while dragged ?